# Python invalid syntax error on con.commit

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am getting this con.commit error and I'm not sure why.

Full Error:

```
File "/Users//Desktop/net/models.py", line 15
    con.commit()
```

models.py

```py
import sqlite3
from os import path

ROOT = path.dirname(path.relpath((__file__)))






def create_post(name, content):
    con = sql.connect(path.join(ROOT, 'database.db'))
    cur = con.cusor()
    cur.execute('insert into posts (name, content) values(?, ?)', (name, content)
    con.commit()
    con.close()




def get_posts():
    con = sql.connect(path.join(ROOT, 'database.db'))
    cur = con.cusor()
    cur.execute('select * from posts')
    posts = cur.fetchall()
    return posts
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Always check the parentheses on the line before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a closing paranthesis missing on line-14.

```
cur.execute('insert into posts (name, content) values(?, ?)', (name, content) **)**
```